# Wordpress prevent post to be saved if condition is true with wp_insert_post_data

Tags: php, wordpress, post, hook

I have a custom plugin that uses custom fields to create a post ( these custom fields will be saved as metas ).

The problem is when these custom meta values are exactly the same for another post.
The task is to throw an error message and not to save the post.
So far i use wp_insert_post_data to trigger my function that checks if this meta values combination already exists for antoher post.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'check_duplicate_relation' , '99', 2 );
```

My question is: how do i stop the post from being created? I tried to return array(), return false, but the post is still created with minimal required values. I know that my function should return altered data but what i tried is to somehow trigger an error message and the post would not be created.

Any ideea how i can do this?...or what hook should i use? As far as i searched this is the one that should be used.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Here is my function:
Where and what i should do?

```
function check_duplicate_relation($data , $postData ) {

if($data['post_type'] == 'bpp_relation' && $data['post_status'] != 'auto-draft') {
    if(isset($postData['fields']) && !empty($postData['fields'])) {
        $bonusProgramId = intval(array_values($postData['fields'])[0]);
        $companyId = intval(array_values($postData['fields'])[1]);

        if($bonusProgramId && $bonusProgramId > 1 && $companyId && $companyId > 1) {
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 2, 
                'post_type' => 'bpp_relation',
                'meta_query' => array(
                     array(
                           'key' => 'company',
                           'value' => $companyId,
                           'compare' => '=',
                     ),
                     array(
                           'key' => 'bonus_program',
                           'value' => $bonusProgramId,
                           'compare' => '=',
                     )
                )
            );

            $relation = get_posts( $args );

            if(empty($relation)) {
                return $data;
            } else {
                // here the error should be returned
            }
        }

    }
}

return $data;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the filter `wp_insert_post_empty_content`. If you return a value that evaluates true, the post will be prevented from being saved. [See in WordPress source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3102).

Comment: I edited my answer, on the line where the error should be returned what should i call?  apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content' ...or add_filter ? I think i tried both but it doesn't work.

Comment: You will want to use `add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'your_function_name', 10, 2)`, to register your filter function, with possibly a different priority than 10. The "2" parameter is important because it will only pass the first argument to your function otherwise. The first variable is the one that stops post creation if it is returned as true. The second one is the post data.

Comment: i used this line of code: add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content' , 'check_duplicate_relation' , '10', 2 );. If my function check_duplicate_relation returns true...it should trigger this empty content error, right?

Comment: Yes, the documentation explains "Returning a truthy value to the filter will effectively short-circuit the new post being inserted"

Comment: But it doesn't. I don't know...maybe i'm doind something wrong...i just can't figure out what.

Comment: Have you tried having your function always return true to make sure there is not a problem with the conditions you are checking inside your function? If it worked then, you could start to debug what might not cause your function to evaluate to true.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct, but this is a funny hook to call since you can't handle an error messsage here, or it is posible?. Indeed, it doesn't save/update the post but the message i get on admin area is: "Post updated". If you have a last answer to this issue, ok. If not ..thanks.

Comment: You're correct that the filter does not allow you to pass your own WP Error. What you can try to do instead is hook into the display of the "Post updated" message when your filter short circuits the post from being updated. See here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169775/26874